# Can I send periodic messages to my Android app users?

Tags: android, message

Is it possible to make a app on Android such that whoever downloads this app receives a message from me weekly? I want to be the only person who can write on this message board and no one else. If this is possible, where should I start looking for tutorials about doing this sort of stuff?

Comment: This sounds like simply having people 'subscribe' to a weekly email newsletter sort of service. Why would they need an android app for that? Your description isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a RSS/Atom feed for yourself. Your android app can then just sync to this feed. Update the feed as often as you like. If you like this approach I can give more details.

Comment: So you feedburner or pubsubhubbub (Google) and set up an RSS feed for your content. Basically your server is serving either  Atom / RSS feeds then.

Answer (score 0):

yes , you can send periodic messages [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071178/android-periodic-service-with-option-to-send-message/26071332#26071332)

```
in that  SendMessage(); function is there so you have to make code for send message to recipient
```